# Opera strange look for input items if width attribute is set

Tags: html, css, opera

I have a very simple case:

On an html page there is only a select box and a button.
They are positioned in one line with flexbox and the select has `flex: 1`.

This works in all major browsers but Opera adds a strange ending to my select box (second variant is when the select box is hovered):

[image]

How can I remove that strange ending?

Here is a minimal example (this is reproducing my issue if you view the page in Opera):

```css
.holder {
  /*display: flex;*/
}

.list {
  /*flex: 1;*/
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;  
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
<select class="list">
<option selected disabled hidden>Please select</option>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
<button class="button">Test</button>
</div>
```

Opera's version is 67.0.3575.97, which I believe is the latest or at least quite up-2-date.

### Update

I've realized this is not linked to flexbox at all.

If I simply set the select box's width, Opera ruins it. (code is updated to provide this simpler example).
Thus, it happens with every input item, even with the button.
The wider the item, the worse the problem is.

This is connected to `-webkit-appearance` of Opera (I have not changed anything, everything is left on default).

Comment: What is the behaviour you are seeing?

Comment: Just have updated!